# Can one iterate a dictionary being modified by another thread without raising exceptions?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a dictionary being updated by one thread, and in another thread I'd like to iterate over its values.  Normally I'd use a lock, but this code is very performance-critical, and I want to avoid that if at all possible.

A special feature of my case is that I don't care about absolute correctness of the iterator; if it misses entries that were removed after iteration started, or picks up ones added afterwards, that's fine.  I only require that it doesn't raise any sort of 'dictionary size changed during iteration' exception.

Given this relaxed constraint on correctness, is there an efficient way to iterate the dictionary without using a lock?

Note: I'm aware that `keys()` is threadsafe in Python 2.x, but since that behavior has changed in 3.x, I want to avoid it.

Comment: What happens if you 'just do it'?

Comment: When it comes to concurrency, I'd rather work from facts than random experiments.

Comment: Bearing in mind the effects of the Global Interpreter Lock, having a lock around your dict might not be as expensive as you think (since your two threads won't be running concurrently anyway).

Comment: I'd love to experiment with this. Would you mind producing a simple self-contained approximation of your code that we could play with (and benchmark)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No personal experience with this, but I read this some time ago: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/

> These operations are thread-safe only to the extent that using them in a thread-unsafe way may cause an exception but will not cause corruption of the internal representation.
>
> As in Python 2.x, mutating a dict while iterating over it using an iterator has an undefined effect and will in most cases raise a RuntimeError exception. (This is similar to the guarantees made by the Java Collections Framework.)

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using a lock long enough to retrieve the values that you want to iterate over:

```
with lock:
    values = the_dict.values() # python 2
    # values = list(the_dict.values()) # python 3
for value in values:
    # do stuff
```

Or, you could try it without a lock and catch `RuntimeError`, and if you get one, try to retrieve the values again.

[edit] Below slightly rephrased per J.F. Sebastian's suggesion:

```
while True:
    try:
        values = list(the_dict.values())
        break
    except RuntimeError:
        pass
```

I personally would go with the lock.

Comment: you could do `while True:\n try: values = list(the_dict.values())\n except RuntimeError: pass\n else: break`

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Dump the keys into a [queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) and read that safely.
2. Performance-critical code should probably not be using Python threads.

Comment: Queues lock internally, and tend to have significantly worse performance than just using a lock directly.  You're perhaps correct about not using Python threads, but that decision is based on a number of other constraints, and isn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an example is better than words.

Array iteration is NOT thread-safe, see [live example for Python 3.6](https://repl.it/@IvanErgunov/iteratedictthreadsafe-1)